# Google Chrome stopped working - NSS version issue

Tags: google-chrome

Suddenly Chrome stopped working, I get this error:

```
jfolpf@toshiba:~$ google-chrome-stable
[7372:7408:1007/230103.985302:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
```

I already updated nss package

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3
```

but no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After several hours I got it, just to let you know.

I was doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3
sudo apt-get update
```

as stated in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46126902/fix-nss-version-not-match-when-update-chrome-in-ubuntu) but nothing.

**You need to upgrade Ubuntu first.** I have now 16.04 LTS

Then, if `apt-get update` returns errors, you need to purge old library

```
sudo apt-get purge libappstream3
```

And then so run those commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3
sudo apt-get update
```

Now google chrome works